# Bluetooth transfer files between android and iOS devices

Tags: bluetooth, file-transfer, ios

I've been tinkering with this for a while, and am pretty sure it's not possible to transfer files using Bluetooth between Iphones (5s at least) and Android (I've tried with a J2).

Please, assume I don't trust the person in the other device, as many of us would like a general solution of file transference. (without the need of any Clouds -icloud, g drive, etc.)

Is this the case? Is it the only way to install an external app? Would you go any other way?

---

**PS:** I've also tried to transfer files from Iphone to my Lenovo 320 ideapad (ubuntu OS), and after hours I gave up. So I'd appreciate any tip on this too.

Comment: Ubuntu OS has known problems with bluetooth. There are 2 places from where the problem can come on all of your devices. The bluetooth version on each of them is different and not compatible with the other or the driver is not good. Try updating your driver and see what will happen. Try with Windows and the driver for Windows. Sometimes there are custom drivers build to revive your PC bluetooth.

Comment: There are apps that are available for Android and iOS that claim do allow sharing via Bluetooth/Wifi. From the PC to the phone via Bluetoth sharing works from my experience only for a very few popular file formats like images.